# MuleSoft 4: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: database, mulesoft, database-cursor, ora-01000

Getting an error

> ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

after processing few records from file inside try-catch scope. I've 3 select statements and 5 stored procedure calls(have insert statement inside stored procedure) in side try-catch scope.

Here is my pooling profile config:

```
<db:pooling-profile maxPoolSize="10" preparedStatementCacheSize="0" />
```

Using default configurations in the stored procedure:

```
<db:stored-procedure doc:name="insert into SPCHG_SERVICE_RENDERED" doc:id="d5b44d97-0f00-4377-a98d-b35a6b78df9e" config-ref="Database_Config" transactionalAction="ALWAYS_JOIN">
            <reconnect count="3" />
            <db:sql ><![CDATA[{call schema.ARRAY_INSERT_SERVICE(:serviceData,:error_num,:error_msg)}]]></db:sql>
            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[{"serviceRenderedData" : payload}]]]></db:input-parameters>
            <db:output-parameters >
                                
                                <db:output-parameter key="error_num" type="INTEGER" />
                                <db:output-parameter key="error_msg" type="VARCHAR" />
                            </db:output-parameters>
        </db:stored-procedure>
```

Runtime: 4.3

Any inputs to fix/avoid this issue.

**Note**: DBA team not going to increase cursor count, looking for solution from MuleSoft end.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are consuming the output of the stored procedure, even if not expecting a result set, by putting the operation in a separate flow inovked with a VM like the [documentation suggest.](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.12/database-connector-troubleshooting#troubleshoot-pooling-profiles-connections-making-the-flow-hang)

Alternatively put a foreach after the db operation.

Comment: thanks for reply. As per requirement, using try scope to maintain transaction (which means either commit all or rollback all) and inside stored proc, I'm not using commit statement, so that if any stored proc fails after few iterations, then it can rollback entire transaction.

Comment: what do you mean by **Alternatively put a foreach after the db operation.** something like this ? ` <flow name="readfileFlow" doc:id="b3445f59-1dc" >
  <try doc:name="Try" doc:id="b1e9129f-2b3f-478b-9ab2-3d1a2ce0b171" >
   <foreach doc:name="Iterate file" doc:id="b42edfd2-2a2d-43cd-acce-5142c0953f59" >
    <db:stored-procedure doc:name="Stored procedure" doc:id="32674acb-c5eb-4f3c-b303-945342defbb9" />
    <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="3b26192f-b725-407b-8932-171c3044b9a5" ><logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="dd7f34e0-37e9" /></foreach></foreach></try> </flow> `

Comment: Yes. Or you can try the method from the documentation. Anything that consumes fully the connection

Comment: tried with below code, but still getting 'maximum open cursors exceeded' issue.  `<try doc:name="Try" doc:id="b1e9129f" transactionalAction="ALWAYS_BEGIN">
<foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="8e840d51" collection="#[payload]">
<db:stored-procedure doc:name="Stored procedure" doc:id="af78201" />
<foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="3b26192f" collection="#[1 to 1]">
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="dd7f34e0" message="inside for-each" />
</foreach></try>`
 Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add version of Oracle DB, version of Oracle JDBC driver, exact version of Mule and patch release, and version of Mule Database connector.

Comment: oracle drive: com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8:19.3.0.0  Runtime: 4.3.0 (Jan 24 2022)  Oracle DB: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.13.0.0.0