Mule 4.5 throwing ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
I am using Mule 4.5 running against an Oracle db instance Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
The mule code that I am running is driven by a scheduler and runs once a day .
It picks up about 12000 emp records once a day and then after some business logic publishes each employee to a queue .
This error occurs on the subscriber side of things when consuming from queue and processing .
Here is the code :
<db:select doc:name="Get Emp Data" config-ref="Emp_Db_Config" >
    <db:sql ><![CDATA[select email,dob,substr(id, 3) as newid,id as oldid   
from employee.emp  
where employee# = :employeeNumber]]></db:sql>
            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[{
    employeeNumber: vars.employeeNumber
}]]]></db:input-parameters>         
</db:select>

Here is the global db config :
<db:config name="Emp_Db_Config" doc:name="Database Config">
        <db:data-source-connection  dataSourceRef="emp-data-source" />
    </db:config>

The datasource is created via spring and am using Hikari connection pool:
<bean id="emp-data-source" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="password" value="xxx"/>     
        <property name="poolName" value="empConnectionPool"/>
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="30"/>
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
    </bean>

pom dependencies and versions :
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

Understood that ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded  means either prepared statement or result set is remaining open , but this is Mule code so ideally it should take care of closing the prepared statement / connection pool ?
Did see some references of issues in Mule ( where connections get leaked  and also here) so have also added below code immediately after the db statement :
<ee:transform doc:name="db connection fix">
  <ee:message>
    <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
      output application/json
      ---
      payload]]>
    </ee:set-payload>
  </ee:message>
  <ee:variables />
</ee:transform>


How are you consuming the output of the query? Did the DataWeave transform resolve the issue? Also see this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71312732/mulesoft-4-ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceeded

I have the data weave transform immediately after the select. Strange thing is when I ran the code again did not get any errors but again on third run facing same issue...

Since we don't have access to your code is not possible to suggest other changes. Try to create a [mre] and [edit] the question to add it.
